# Cloudfront authorization with my own server

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to use urls like http://example.com/image.jpg?token=123abc
When downloading the file, cloudfront ask my own server whether this token is valid and determine to allow/reject download.

Is this possible?

I have read some documents on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html but seems useless for me:(

Comment: An important distinction between the "useless" link you cited (note: not really useless, but you have to understand how/why it works) and what you're discussing is that when you want CloudFront to determine whether a request is authorized, it doesn't "ask" your server -- it does its own validation of the request, before forwarding to the origin or serving from cache.  If any credentials are passed to the server, such as via the query string or via a `Cookie:` or the `Authorization:` header, that response can only be served from cache if a subsequent request includes the *identical* parameter.

Comment: Whether CloudFront can do what you want, and how to accomplish that, depends on what you are *really* trying to accomplish.  If you want the content that is subject to authorization checks to be potentially served from cache, you will need to use signed URLs or signed cookies, which your server can send to the browser so that requests can be authorized.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your CloudFront distribution to forward query parameters, that way the token will be passed to your server which is free to return 200 OK with the content or 403 Forbidden. The downside with this is that CloudFront doesn't cache the content once - either once per token or not at all